# are Phonegap hydra message editable?

Tags: phonegap, hydration

We are using Phonegap hydration service in our Hybrid mobile application, in order to keep our mobile app always up to date without needing to push our update through apple submission process.So when we create a new updated build a text in the application notify the user about the update.

Message:
"Hydra has detected a new Update!
A new version of this application is available from build.phonegap.com .
You can return to this screen to check for an update anytime using a 3-finger tap"

So comes my question, can this message be modified to a custom text message in any way?